# What is MSVC /Zp alternative on GCC and clang?

Tags: windows, gcc, clang, cl, struct-member-alignment

In case, i want to define the structure alignment at a module level using the compiler flags such as [/Zp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh3e3fd0.aspx) for cl on windows. What are the alternatives on GCC and clang?

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -v --help` gives:

```
-fpack-struct               Pack structure members together without holes
-fpack-struct=<number>      Set initial maximum structure member alignment
```

clang has the same switch (at least clang 3.x).

Comment: On msdn for Zp, it is mentioned that "Packs structures on 8-byte boundaries (default)." Does that mean that if there a data type of size > 8 bytes, by default it would not be naturally aligned and rather will have 8 byte alignment.

If yes, is that case with GCC/clang?

Comment: @AbhishekJain sorry I don't know that